# How can excite a semiconductor to make a photon just by heat in room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, photons, semiconductor-physics

I want to know if a semiconductor in room temperature can excite by heat, producing photon, without any other source of energy?

Comment: You don't need a semiconductor for that. All materials will emit electromagnetic radiation with a thermal spectrum at all temperatures.

Comment: But with regard to a semiconductor, since the equilibrium carrier concentrations are the net result of generation and recombination, and the recombination may emit a photon, the general answer is yes, photons are emitted by a semiconductor in thermal equilibrium. Just not very many.

Comment: Dear Jon Custer please help me more about semiconductors. I have some other questions. How can you answer me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and it is unavoidable.

Let's consider an intrinsic semiconductor for simplicity.   If the semiconductor is at the absolute zero of temperature, then all electrons will be in the valence band.  At any non-zero temperature there is a chance that some electrons will have been promoted by thermal agitation into the conduction band.  These electrons will not stay there long; they will soon drop back down to the valance band emitting a photon.  On the whole, electrons are constantly being promoted and subsequently dropping down.  There is a constant emission of radiation.

The likelihood of an electron being promoted is determined by the temperature and the band gap $E_g$.   If $kT$ is on the order of $E_g$, many photons will be emitted.  If $kT$ is much less than $kT$ then very few will be emitted. $kT$ at room temperature is 0.025 eV, and band gaps are around 1 eV, so generally there not a lot of photons generated, but what constitutes "a lot" depends on the application.

So narrow-band semiconductors like germanium, are more "noisy" than higher band materials, GaN for example.  If you are building an optical detector thermal generation of photons can be a problem because the thermally generated photons will be detected along with the signal of interest.  To largely eliminate this problem, optical detectors are frequently cooled.

The same thing applies to an insulators, by the way. Nothing special about semiconductors.

Comment: Dear Jon Custer please help me more about semiconductors. I have some other questions. How can you answer me? Thanks

Comment: @hosseinyazdi  If you have further questions, you should either start a new question, or if the questions concern clarifications of this one you should edit your original question.